# What base system satisfies the equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For the equation:
$$5x^2 - 50x +125 = 0$$

$x=5$ and $x=8$ are solutions.

This is in another base, what are the steps required to find out what base it is in?

Thanks

Comment: The base does not matter.  The equation will have the same solutions in any base.  Although, the solutions will look different.  $x=8$ is not a solution.  It doesn't check.  Notice that all the coefficients are divisible by $5$. So, divide both sides by $5$ and you should be able to solve by factoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b$ be the base of the coefficients in the quadratic. Then, $(50)_b = 5b$ and $(125)_b = b^2+2b+5$.

Hence, the quadratic in base-$10$ is $5x^2-5bx+(b^2+2b+5) = 0$.

Since $x = 5$ is a solution, we have $125 - 25b + (b^2+2b+5) = 0$, i.e. $b^2-23b+130 = 0$.

Since $x = 8$ is a solution, we have $320 - 40b + (b^2+2b+5) = 0$, i.e. $b^2-38b+325 = 0$.

Can you find what value of $b$ satisfies both of these conditions?